# Session expired but I can still visit block urls with Spring Shiro

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

When the session expired,I can't read informations in session.But I can still visit my block urls.Then I can only by visit /logout after that the shiro work again.What happened ? I need shiro blocks when session expired,how can I do?

```
Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/favicon.ico", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/images/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/js/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/css/**", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/fonts/**", "anon");

    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");

    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/register", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "roles[admin],perms[admin]");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/confirmorder/**", "authc");

    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");

    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/index");
```

this is my shiroconfig

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, when the session expires you can vist any of these URLs except `/confirmorder/**`.  You can add `authc` to your `/admin/**` route and you should be all set.